# Jquery button selecting all checkboxed within a div and button selecting all on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi i could really do with some help on this as I cannot get the button to select all checkboxes within .voltSiteResultContainer to work

**HTML Example:**

```
 <div class="pageContainer">
<input type="button" class="check" value="check all"> // want this button to check all on page
<div class="voltSiteResultContainer">
    <div class="checkWrap">
        <input type="button" class="checkSite" value="check all"> // want this button to check all within .voltSiteResultContainer
    </div>
    <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583">
    <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583">
    <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583">
</div>
<div class="voltSiteResultContainer">
    <div class="checkWrap">
        <input type="button" class="checkSite" value="check all"> // want this button to check all within .voltSiteResultContainer
    </div>
    <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583">
    <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583">
    <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583">
</div>
```

**Current Jquery:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
            $(this).val('uncheck all')
        },function(){
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).val('check all');        
        })
    })
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.checkSite:button').toggle(function(){
            .closest('.voltSiteResultContainer').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
            $(this).val('uncheck all')
        },function(){
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).val('check all');        
        })
    })
```

So $('.check:button') work but $('.checkSite:button') is not :(.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me :)

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ojihos/1/edit)*

Add `$(this)` in line 11 - and a missing `</div>` in your HTML:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   
        $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
            $(this).val('uncheck all');
        },function(){
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).val('check all');        
        });

        $('.checkSite:button').toggle(function(){
            $(this).closest('.voltSiteResultContainer').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked'); // HERE!!
            $(this).val('uncheck all');
        },function(){
            $(this).closest('.voltSiteResultContainer').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).val('check all');        
        });
              
});
```

Fixed HTML markup:

```
<div class="pageContainer">
    <input type="button" class="check" value="check all" /> // want this button to check all on page
    <div class="voltSiteResultContainer">
      <div class="checkWrap">
         <input type="button" class="checkSite" value="check all" /> // want this button to check all within .voltSiteResultContainer
      </div>
      <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583" />
      <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583" />
      <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583" />
    </div>  
</div>
     
<div class="voltSiteResultContainer">
    <div class="checkWrap">
      <input type="button" class="checkSite" value="check all" /> // want this button to check all within .voltSiteResultContainer
    </div>
   <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583" />
   <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583" />
   <input name="checkFile" type="checkbox" class="checkFile" value="1514583" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko, really appreciate the help, you have to love StackOverflow answered in less thaqn 5 mins... cheers man :)